# How to ignore @JsonProperty while converting object to map by Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

For example, I have a class `User` which has only 2 fields - `name` and `identification` which annotated by `@JsonProperty` respectively. And I use `Jackson` to convert this object to a `Map`, but the result is not what I expected. I want to the all the keys in the result map to be what I declared in `User`, not the value in `@JsonProperty`.

**Class User**

```
class User {
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int identification;

    //constructor, getters, setters and toString
}
```

**Code snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = new User("Bob", 123);
System.out.println(user.toString());

Map<String, Object> result = mapper.convertValue(user, Map.class);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

**Console output**

> User [name=Bob, identification=123]
>   {username=Bob, id=123}

But what I expected output for map is as follows. The field name should be the same defined in class **User**, not the value specified in `@JsonProperty`. BTW, I cannot remove the `@JsonProperty` because they are used for serialization/deserialization somewhere.

> {name=Bob, identification=123}

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When you say you can't remove the `@JsonProperty` where it is used. You have to either remove the `JsonProperty` or modify where it has been used.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@JsonProperty` and modify it where it has been used ? What were the results ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to configure your object mapper like this (but it will ignore all annotation)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);
```

---

I have found another way that turns off only name setting from @JsonProperty and leave another property from @JsonProperty and another Jackson annotations. If you want to turn off some extra annotations(or part of annotation) - override method which implements it

```
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector( new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
            @Override
            public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just simply remove the JsonProperty. Then it will automatically map to the property name.

`JsonProperty` annotation just help you specify the field name which is different to your property name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have mentioned that I cannot remove that annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **@JsonProperty** from fields

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have mentioned that I cannot remove that annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I know several ways to achieve it:

1. Is to use @JsonSetter & @JsonGetter to manipulate serialization/deserialization names. An example:

   ```
   @JsonGetter("name")
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   //# Used during deserialization
   @JsonSetter("username")
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   ```
2. To use [@JsonAlias](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9.pr1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html) to provide an alias for desirialization